# Register stream event handler after event happens

Tags: node.js, events, promise, stream

Say i have a node.js stream `myStream`, and i register an event on this stream

```
const promiseResult = await longPromise()

myStream.on('end', () => {
  console.log(42)
})
```

---

What happens if the `end` event happens during the awaited promise? Will the handler run after the actual `end` event has happened?

Comment: No. Event handlers are only triggered for future events.

Comment: No. as jorgenkg said. Your await prevents that the event handler get registers until it resolvs. So you would "loose"/miss the fired event.

Comment: Ok, I suppose there might be some documentation that explains this in more detail...  Would be nice to have a way of insuring all handlers are registered before the events actually happens.